# Access violation termination calling slasd4 mex

Tags: matlab, mex, lapack

I'm trying to construct a MEX file to call the Lapack command `slasd4` in MATLAB. Building the mex file succeeds, but when I try to use the command it crashes MATLAB and ends with the message

> Abnormal termination: Access violation.

Can anyone please help me to fix this problem? I'm using MATLAB R2016b with the built-in add-on for using MEX files.

Here is my mex file:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "lapack.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs,       mxArray *plhs[], 
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSize n, i, info = 0;
    float  *z, *d, *delta, *work, *sigma, rho;

    /* verify input/output arguments */
    if (nrhs > 4) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many input arguments.");
    }
    if (nlhs > 3) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");
    }

    /* dimensions of input matrix */
    n = mxGetN(prhs[0]); 

    /* create output matrices */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(n, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    plhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(n, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    plhs[2] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

    /* get pointers to data */
    i     = (mwSignedIndex) prhs[3];

    d     = (float *) mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    z     = (float *) mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    rho   = (float)   mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);        

    delta = (float *) mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    work  = (float *) mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
    sigma = (float *) mxGetPr(plhs[2]);

    /* Call Lapack function */
    slasd4(&n, &i, d, z, delta, &rho, sigma, work, &info);

    /* check if call was successful */
    if (info < 0) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Illegal values in arguments.");
    } else if (info > 0) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Failed to converge.");
    }
}
```

Here is a simple test example:

```
D = [2; 0];
z = [1;0];
[delta, work, sigma] = slasd4(D,z,-1,1);
```

Here's the beginning stack trace from fault:

```
[  0] 0x000000000b8c15b0      C:\Users\Joni\Desktop\NLA\Paper\slasd4.mexw64+00005552 mexfilerequiredapiversion+00000032
[  1] 0x000000000b8c1561      C:\Users\Joni\Desktop\NLA\Paper\slasd4.mexw64+00005473 mexFunction+00000305
[  2] 0x00000000fc5fc5d1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00116177 mexRunMexFile+00000129
[  3] 0x00000000fc5fb2e2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00111330 mexFeature_mexver+00001794
[  4] 0x00000000fc5fa506 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00107782 mexUnlock+00020182
```

Comment: I don't know the normal signature in C for `slasd4`, but the fact that you're passing it only pointers already strikes me as odd...

Comment: Also, `n` is unsigned (`mwSize`), `i` is signed (`mwSignedIndex`), that is odd. Moreover, you can't cast pointers to `mxArrays` into `mwSignedIndex` to get their sizes...Don't you mean to call `mxGetN()`?

Comment: Can you provide a link to some sort of documentation on `slasd4` used in this sort of context?

Comment: Also, you will get an access violation if you call `slasd4(1)` in MATLAB, because you haven't checked what happens when `nrhs < 4` but are still directly indexing `prhs[3]`.

Comment: That's in Fortran, but you're writing in C. What does the signature of the C wrapper look like?

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings? Try compiling with `/w4 /wX`

Comment: (`mex COMPFLAGS="/w4 /wx" slasd4.c`)

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. I'm a real beginner to the programming language C, so I created this file mainly on examples I could find on the internet. That's where I found the mwSignedIndex, but maybe it should just be mwSize like the other one. i is an index that you give as an input parameter, so I think mxGetN() should not work since this returns the dimension of an array.  Maybe I could use mxGetScalar() with i .

Comment: This is the c code for slasd4: [link](https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/gems/ruby-lapack/1.6/files/ext/slasd4.c)

Comment: Well you're casting a pointer to an `mxArray` to an integer without an explicit cast, and then pass it on to `slas4d`...That's going to raise some alarm bell sooner or later, quite probably at OS level (e.g., MATLAB tried to access stuff it doesn't have access to)

Comment: Normally, you get compiler warnings about this, that's why I asked...

Comment: I tried your line for compiling and don't get any compiler warnings.

Comment: Just try with `mxGetScalar()`, see that that does. I strongly suspect that that's your problem

Comment: I tried and changed "i     = (mwSignedIndex) prhs[3];" to "i     = (mwSize) mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);", the error sadly stays the same.

Comment: OK...do you know how to debug mex files?

Comment: do you still have this problem?

Comment: I apologize for answering so slow. Apparantely the LAPACK command I wanted to use wouldn't work. Therefore I solved my task in an other way which didn't require a MEX file. Thanks for looking info my question.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems related to data types etc.  All of the integer variables used for BLAS and LAPACK calls using the MATLAB supplied libraries should normally be typed as mwSignedIndex, not mwSize.  Also, if the underlying data type of the variables being passed in are doubles, you can't magically change that data to float just by pointing a (float *) at them. So you need to ensure that the input data is the correct class.  Up front, you should be putting in a *lot* more checks for variable class and size etc.  Here is some code with additional up-front checks, along with a couple of code corrections:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "lapack.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs,       mxArray *plhs[], 
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
mwSignedIndex n, i, info = 0;  /* CHANGED */
float  *z, *d, *delta, *work, *sigma, rho;
mxArray *plhs0, *plhs1, *plhs2;  /* NEW */

/* verify input/output arguments */
if (nrhs != 4) {  /* CHANGED */
    mexErrMsgTxt("Need exactly 4 inputs.");  /* CHANGED */
}
if (nlhs > 3) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");
}
/* NEW */
if( !mxIsSingle(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) ) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("1st argument must be a real single class variable");
}
if( !mxIsSingle(prhs[1]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[1]) ) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("2nd argument must be a real single class variable");
}
if( !mxIsNumeric(prhs[2]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[2]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[2]) != 1 ) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("3rd argument must be a real numeric scalar variable");
}
if( !mxIsNumeric(prhs[3]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[3]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[3]) != 1 ) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("4th argument must be a real numeric scalar variable");
}

/* dimensions of input matrix */
n = mxGetN(prhs[0]); 

/* create output matrices */
plhs0 = mxCreateNumericMatrix(n, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);  /* CHANGED */
plhs1 = mxCreateNumericMatrix(n, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);  /* CHANGED */
plhs2 = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);  /* CHANGED */

/* get pointers to data */
i     = (mwSignedIndex) mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);  /* CHANGED */
d     = (float *) mxGetData(prhs[0]);  /* CHANGED */
z     = (float *) mxGetData(prhs[1]);  /* CHANGED */
rho   = (float)   mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);        

delta = (float *) mxGetData(plhs0);  /* CHANGED */
work  = (float *) mxGetData(plhs1);  /* CHANGED */
sigma = (float *) mxGetData(plhs2);  /* CHANGED */

/* Call Lapack function */
slasd4(&n, &i, d, z, delta, &rho, sigma, work, &info);

/* check if call was successful */
if (info < 0) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("Illegal values in arguments.");
} else if (info > 0) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("Failed to converge.");
}
plhs[0] = plhs0;  /* NEW */
if( nlhs > 1 ) plhs[1] = plhs1;  /* NEW */
if( nlhs > 2 ) plhs[2] = plhs2;  /* NEW */
}
```

And here is the result of a run:

```
>> D = [2; 0];
>> z = [1;0];
>> [delta, work, sigma] = slasd4(D,z,-1,1)
??? Error using ==> slasd4
1st argument must be a real single class variable

>> [delta, work, sigma] = slasd4(single(D),z,-1,1)
??? Error using ==> slasd4
2nd argument must be a real single class variable

>> [delta, work, sigma] = slasd4(single(D),single(z),-1,1)
delta =
     1
work =
     1
sigma =
    1.7321
```

I only made enough changes to get you past the seg fault.  I didn't check anything about the actual function call itself to make sure you have the correct dimensions for the work variable, or that the variables have appropriate data, etc.